# Kotlin & Mockito unit tests failing in gradle

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

Running unit tests locally on Android Studio works fine but when I run it with gradle using `./gradlew test`. The tests fails with the exception saying Mockito cannot spy/mock final classes. I thought using mockito with the inline extension was supposed to fix this. I have this dependency 
 in my gradle file `testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.18.0"`

Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped me, is to create a `MockMaker` file and to put it into test resources.

File
`org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` (literally) that contains only this line

```
mock-maker-inline
```

and place it into
`test/resources/mockito-extensions`.
Answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50449830/3569545